# How to Query in google sheets, sort by a column and not include that column in the output

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to query in google sheets and sort the query by a specific column in accending order, and have a secondary sort that is also in ascending order. I already know how to do this by

```
=QUERY(A:C,"select * where month(A)+1 = 1 order by A,B ",0)
```

Here i queried 3 columns month, unique ID, and name. I selected the data with the necessary month, and sorted it by month, followed by a secondary sort of unique ID. But this query outputs 3 columns. How would i change the formula so the output does not include the month column anymore.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is:

> How would i change the formula so the output does not include the month column anymore.

Try wrapping your `QUERY` formula within another `QUERY`. Like:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(your_query_here),"select Col2, Col3")
```

For your given example it would be:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A1:C22,"select * where month(A)+1 = 1 order by A,B ",0),
         "select Col1, Col3")
```

Comment: Ahhh thats a great solution, i never would have thought of that. Thank you

Comment: And it might be of not that "Col1" is case sensitive, letter 'C' must be capitalized